# Grails as400 / iSeries Database generate

Tags: grails, ibm-midrange

Does anyone know if it's possible to autogenerate a database on the as400 / iSeries via the domain classes in a grails application as you can  do for other DB's ?   I can use existing tables via mappings  but i'm trying to create a new app and it won't create new tables for me  ..

My datasource ..

```
dbcreate = "create-drop"
           username = "user"
           password = "password"
           driverClassName = "com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver"
           url = "jdbc:as400://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;naming=system;libraries=,SAMPLEDB;date    format=iso;prompt=false;translate binary=true"
        dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.DB2400Dialect"
```

But this just throws an error basically saying it can't find the files that i'm writing to via bootstrap  ..  Anyone know if it's possible ? .. Fwiw i'm on v5r4 of the os/400 OS - and yes I  know it's old and not supported anymore  ..

Thanks

Comment: Why are you writing files? Isn't it just a matter of running DDL commands in the database?

Comment: It is .. but  it's so much easier when Grails generates the files for you .. I spotted my error , typo - used 'dbcreate' instead of 'dbCreate' .. But thanks Burt ..